# compare two states using a combination of predictors in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

When using Logistic regression concept in an example, I want to compare the risk of the disease (response) for a 25 year male who smokes with a 50 year male who does not smoke.
Response would be if the patient has the disease or not.
How are we suppose to consider 3 predictors in a comparison (Age, Gender and smoke) in R programming?

Comment: What is meant by "consider 3 predictors in a comparison"? What do "consider" and "comparison" refer to? Do you simply want to apply logistic regression with input features (age, gender, smoke) and response (disease) and just would like to know how to do this in R?